# Display app status in top bar

Tags: iphone, sdk, iphone-privateapi

The Evernote iPhone app displays a "second" status bar at the top to keep the user informed about the progress of the synchronization without blocking the rest of the user interface.

You can see the green bar in this screenshot:
http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/5024/fotowx.png

How would you implement such a bar? Moving down the view of the navigation controller and adding the status bar as a subview to the window?

Is it even called status bar? Didn't know how to name it..

Thanks in advance for your answers
Martin

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found this link to the [SBStatusBarController](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SBStatusBarController). So this answers the remaining questions.

Thanks again!

Comment: Since iOS4.0, SBStatusBarController moved to UIStatusBar, which is now in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started looking for this too. I just saw this browsing on my iPhone, so I haven't checked to see if this is directly applicable or functional, but this *might* be what we want:

http://www.cocoabyss.com/uikit/custom-status-bar-ios/

[EDIT]

I don't think this is what we're after ... It looks like it's just an overlay for the main status bar ... not an animated insert of a second status bar...

Comment: But nice to know! Thanks anyway!

Comment: This seems to be the best implementation to get us "close" to Evernote.  https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay  ... It doesn't get us the attractive double-height bar like the newer Evernote, but it's not bad.

Comment: I love all the folks on GitHub who see some cool UI element in a new app and recreate it for the masses ... this is one of those cases.  Awesomeness!
https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKInfoPanelDemo

Answer (score 0):

This is the `doubleHeightStatusBar`. It is available in the `UIStatusBar` class and is only accessible if you have a jailbroken device with the Private Framework headers.

I'm not sure how Evernote obtained this and passed Apple approval.

Comment: <quote>
I'm not sure how Evernote obtained this and passed Apple approval.
</quote>
That's what I'm asking myself.

Comment: Ok my app is distributed ad-hoc. Does the double size status bar only work on JB-devices?
And do you know any documentation for that beast?

Comment: Reeder has the same implementation, so it can't be a conspiracy.

Comment: It would be pretty easy to create a single parent view with a custom bar at the top, and a standard `UINavigationController` in the space beneath it. No need to use `doubleHeightStatusBar` at all.

Comment: @e.James That may go against Apple HIG though.

Comment: @WrightCS: The G does stand for *guidelines* `:)` There are plenty of accepted apps that do not follow Apple's HIG to the letter.